# How to get Cookies in CURL request using PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I have two files: A.php and B.php.

Contents of A.php:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curlsetopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'localhost/b.php');
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Contents of B.php:

```
<?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

it isn't printing COOKIES when loading A.php but printing when loading b.php directly.please help
thanks

Comment: You are not printing the result in `A.php`.

Comment: Because you didn't specify any cookie before executing the cURL?

Comment: When you load `B.php` from your browser, any cookies would be stored/read on your local browser session. When loading `B.php` via cURL through `A.php`, `B` would look for cookies on the browser session than made the request (`cURL` on `localhost`) not your local browser session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL requests don't send cookies by default.  If you want to pass all of the `$_COOKIE`s from script a.php to b.php do this:

```
<?php

$cookie = array();

foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
    $cookie[] = "{$key}={$value}";
};

$cookie = implode('; ', $cookie);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'localhost/b.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_exec($ch);
```